# changing an image into another image and then resets back to default image when another different image is clicked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, image

How will I change my image and the roll it back to default image when I click another image using angularjs? I am new to angular and here is my code

```
    <div ng-controller="SwapControl">

    <img  ng-click="myData.swapHere()" ng-src="{{myData.images.current}}"  alt="image to be swapped">
  </div>
  <script>
  var myApp = angular.module("swap", []);

myApp.controller('SwapControl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {};

  $scope.myData.images = {

    initialImage: "http://creativecurio.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/vm-logo-sm-1.gif",
    finalImage: "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=1247787",
    current : "http://creativecurio.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/vm-logo-sm-1.gif"
  };
  $scope.myData.swapHere = function() {

       if($scope.myData.images.current === $scope.myData.images.finalImage)
          $scope.myData.images.current = $scope.myData.images.initialImage
        else if($scope.myData.images.current === $scope.myData.images.initialImage) 
          $scope.myData.images.current = $scope.myData.images.finalImage
      };


  $scope.myData1 = {};

  $scope.myData1.images = {
    initialImage: "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg",
    finalImage: "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=1247787",
    current : "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg"
  };
  $scope.myData1.swapHere = function() {
       if($scope.myData1.images.current === $scope.myData1.images.finalImage)
          $scope.myData1.images.current = $scope.myData1.images.initialImage
        else if($scope.myData1.images.current === $scope.myData1.images.initialImage) 
          $scope.myData1.images.current = $scope.myData1.images.finalImage
      };


});

</script>
 <div ng-controller="SwapControl">

    <img ng-click="myData1.swapHere()" ng-src="{{myData1.images.current}}"  alt="image to be swapped">
  </div>

</body>
```

here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/zPxqPjB4M1sis16SF7Jn?p=preview

Comment: Your script in plunker doesn't work, because you have `$scope.myData.images = {
    tabindex="0";...` and should be `tabindex: "0",`.

Comment: It works now @EganWolf all I need now is how can I possibly return the first image into its initial image when I click the second image at the same time the second image also changes into another image

Comment: hi again @EganWolf . Sorry for bugging you again but I also want to add another event to this which is the mouse over.. Everytime I will hover the mouse I also want the final image to show and when click swap it. How can I possibly do that? Thanks. You've been a great help!

Comment: I answered in comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your images are controlled by two diffrent instances of the same controller. Then, every image is in diffrent scope so first image can't be controlled by the second one. To change this, move your `ng-controller` attribute to `<body>` element.

Now you can change `ng-click` attribute for second image and use the function that changes first image. Below is a working code:

```
<body ng-app="swap" ng-cpontroller="SwapControl">
    <div>
        <img  ng-click="myData.swapHere()" ng-src="{{myData.images.current}}" alt="image to be swapped">
    </div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module("swap", []);

myApp.controller('SwapControl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = {};

  $scope.myData.images = {
    initialImage: "http://creativecurio.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/vm-logo-sm-1.gif",
    finalImage: "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=1247787",
    current : "http://creativecurio.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/vm-logo-sm-1.gif"
  };
  $scope.myData.swapHere = function() {
       $scope.myData1.images.current = $scope.myData1.images.initialImage
       if($scope.myData.images.current === $scope.myData.images.finalImage)
          $scope.myData.images.current = $scope.myData.images.initialImage
       else if($scope.myData.images.current === $scope.myData.images.initialImage) 
          $scope.myData.images.current = $scope.myData.images.finalImage
      };


  $scope.myData1 = {};

  $scope.myData1.images = {
    initialImage: "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg",
    finalImage: "http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=1247787",
    current : "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg"
  };

  $scope.myData1.swapHere = function() {
       $scope.myData.images.current = $scope.myData.images.initialImage
       if($scope.myData1.images.current === $scope.myData1.images.finalImage)
          $scope.myData1.images.current = $scope.myData1.images.initialImage
       else if($scope.myData1.images.current === $scope.myData1.images.initialImage) 
          $scope.myData1.images.current = $scope.myData1.images.finalImage
      };
});
</script>

    <div>
        <img ng-click="myData1.swapHere()" ng-src="{{myData1.images.current}}"  alt="image to be swapped">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks @EganWolf  but when I copied it to my plunker its not working

Comment: I made it work @EganWolf but it seems that the second image wasn't changing. I also do want to change the second image when I click it

Comment: how will I change it @EganWolf? like this ng-click="myData1.swapHere()"?but when I did this the second image doesn't control the other one

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to add `$scope.myData1.swapHere()` somewhere in the `$scope.myData.swapHere` function. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @EganWolf but when I tried it, the images change at the same time. The image that should change is the one clicked and then when the other image is clicked, the first image will return to its initial image at the same time the second image will change

Comment: Ok, I think I see now what you need. I updated my answer. I changed `swapHere` functions and put `myData1.swapHere()` function back to second image.

Comment: Thanks @EganWolf ! you're great :D

Comment: hi again @EganWolf . Sorry for bugging you again but I also want to add another event to this which is the mouse over.. Everytime I will hover the mouse I also want the final image to show and when click swap it. How can I possibly do that? Thanks. You've been a great help!

Comment: There is similar to `ng-click` attribute for mouseover event: `ng-mouseover`. Just add new function, something like `$scope.systemImg.init = function() {
       $scope.systemImg.images.current = $scope.systemImg.images.initialImage;
      };` and bound it to this attribute in your first image.

Comment: hi again but the hover technique that you suggested seems to be not working is there any other possible way?

Comment: There is typo in your plunker in `$scope.systemImg.out` function in `InitialImage` (first letter is uppercase).

Comment: @bleykFaust was that your problem? Or there is something else?

Comment: thanks for that :) but my problem is that when I want to click the image that is in hover I can't click it. It returns to the initial image simultaneously with the other image. I edited my plunker already

Comment: With `ng-mouseover` you change image to final, then with click you swap clicked image (so it changes to initial) and set two another images to initial. If you don't want to change image to initial with click, then you have to change your `swapHere()` function.